# How to see the arguments types of the methods from the superclasses when overriding methods in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I extend from a class which has many overloaded methods (same name, different argument). I would like to override one of these methods, but the box with suggestions contains method names only without types. Is there a setting for it?

[image: overriding a method from a superclass which contains many overloaded methods]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to select a method that I want to override/implement. There are all methods which possibly can be overridden/implemented with a full signature and a return type in the opening dialog box.

If the "Quick Documentation" feature is configurated as a popup, also it is convenient to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> on the selected suggestion to see this method documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the suggestions that you see in dropdown, you can use `ctrl`+`q` when you are in suggestion mode (`ctrl`+`space`)  which brings up documentation of currently selected method in the suggestion list. You can move up /down by arrows and see documentation of each method and its signature (argument type).

Alternatively you use the `ctrl`+`o` as suggested by Andrew.

[image]